# jQuery Datatable Editor not initializing

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I am currently using datatable in a page. However, when I try adding datatable editor plug-in, I am getting errors in the console:

```
TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.Editor is not a constructor
```

All I did was add the following lines in the jquery of creating a table:

```
 var table = $('#sampledt').DataTable();
 var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor(table);
 new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons( table, [
  { 
    extend: "edit", editor: editor 
  },
  { 
    extend: "remove", editor: editor 
  }
]);

table.buttons().container()
     .appendTo( $('col-sm-6:eq(0)', table.table().container() ));
```

These are the .js and .css in the page:

```
jquery-1.12.0.min.js
bootstrap.min.js
jquery.dataTables.min.js
dataTables.bootstrap.min.js
dataTables.buttons.min.js
buttons.bootstrap.min.js
dataTables.select.min.js
dataTables.editor.min.js

bootstrap.min.css
dataTables.bootstrap.min.css
buttons.bootstrap.min.css
select.bootstrap.min.css
editor.bootstrap.min.css
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I added the var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor(table);
The console error of 'editor' not being defined was removed. Instead, a new error occurred: $.fn.dataTable.Editor is not a constructor.

**UPDATE:**

I removed the bootstrap.min.js from the page. The console error 
"TypeError: a.Editor is undefined" was removed.

Comment: is the `editor` variable you assign to `"edit"` defined somewhere? how?

Comment: hello, I assigned it as: var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor(sampledt); However, I got an error: $.fn.dataTable.Editor is not a constructor

Comment: shouldn't it be `editor()` lowercase?

Comment: I changed it but unfortunately, the error is still there. T.T

Comment: what kind of object is `table` you use to construct `editor`?

Answer (score 5):

are you using file from a Free trial version? ensure that you have purchased the editor or get newer files within the trial period

Answer (score -1):

I guess you missed initialization. You need to initialize the variable `editor` and assign it the value like:

```
var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {} );
```

Comment: hello, I assigned 'editor' in a dataTable.Editor as follows: var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor(sampledt);   However, I am having another error in console: $.fn.dataTable.Editor is not a constructor

Comment: What is this editor.bootstrap.min.js file for? Can you remove it once and check

Comment: hello, I removed the editor.boostrap.min.js from the page. Now, the console "TypeError: a.Editor is undefined" was gone. I am now left with "TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.Editor is not a constructor" error